# Why does Visual Studio Code force me to use a remote GitHub repository?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Having initialised a local repo and made an initial commit, VS code prompts me to 'Publish Branch' on GitHub.

I don't want to use GitHub as I am happy using a local repo in this case. Is this possible? I can't find an option to ignore the 'Publish Branch' prompt.

Before initializing a repository:

[image: pre init]

After initializing a repository:

[image: after init]

After committing:

[image: after commit]

Comment: Microsoft, who makes VSCode, acquired Github in 2018. https://news.microsoft.com/announcement/microsoft-acquires-github/

Comment: And it's not really forcing you to publish to Github. You can safely just ignore it or push to a different remote repo.

Comment: @GinoMempin but I can't ignore it - it won't let me use the repo locally.

Comment: @Jellyboy I'm aware.

Comment: @obevan you are doing something wrong. I am right now using VSCode with a remote on Bitbucket and vscode is 100% happy with it.

Comment: Why some piece of GUI software behaves the way it does is not a programming question. You are not prevented from using Git however you like so there is no issue to answer.

Comment: @Jellyboy Of course I am, but I don't know what. It's a clean install of VSCode but as soon as I commit having initialised a repo it asks me to publish the branch to GitHub. I just want to use the repo locally.

Comment: What do you mean by a "local repo"? Do you mean you just do `git commit` but don't `git push` anywhere? I am quite sure that the Source Control UI doesn't block you from just doing local commits. The buttons are just there if have no remote configured.

Comment: @matt I appreciate that but my question is with a 'software tools commonly used by programmers' as StackOverflow suggests valid questions need be.

Comment: @GinoMempin Indeed, I'm used to using the source control in Xcode where I also don't push anywhere, just commit, and that has never tried to force me to publish to any remote.

Comment: Then as I've said, it's not forcing you to. You can keep doing local commits, the button is just there as long as you have no remotes configured, but it shouldn't be blocking you from local commits. I don't understand "*it won't let me use the repo locally*"

Comment: @GinoMempin Okay I understand - thanks for your help. Just thought it looked a little odd as it differed from (albeit old) docs showing nothing, seemed intrusive, and was different to what I'm used to. Thanks for clearing up, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really forcing you or prompting you to publish your repo to Github.

It's more of an option, a hint, or a recommendation, since when someone uses Git, they typically would want to push/publish their local copy of the repo to some remote copy of the same repo (ex. for sharing with other members of your team, etc.). But it's perfectly fine with Git *and* with Visual Studio Code's Source Control functions if all you want is to maintain it all locally. It shouldn't be blocking you from doing further local commits.

So

> I don't want use GitHub do as I am happy using a local repo in this case - is this possible?

**YES.**

> I can't find an option to ignore the 'Publish Branch' prompt.

If you don't want to see that button, you can hide it with the setting **Git: Show Unpublished Commits** introduced in [VS Code 1.61 September 2021](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_61#_publish-or-sync-action-button-for-git-repositories)

> By default, the Git extension will add a **Sync Changes** button as shown above, if there are unpushed commits, or a **Publish Changes** button if the branch hasn't yet been published. Additionally, users can customize this behavior by configuring the `git.showUnpublishedCommitsButton` setting, which defaults to `whenEmpty` so that the button will only be shown if there are unpushed commits and there are no other changes in the view.

[image: git.showUnpublishedCommitsButton settings UI]

```json
"git.showUnpublishedCommitsButton": "never"
```

> Just thought it looked a little odd as it differed from (albeit old) docs showing nothing, seemed intrusive, and was different to what I'm used to.

It's probably part of the continuous updates that further integrated Github with VS Code's UI ([since both are now owned by Microsoft](https://news.microsoft.com/announcement/microsoft-acquires-github/)). The section on [Initializing a Repository](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_initialize-a-repository) doesn't mention that it's required to publish to Github or to any other provider.

And to be clear, you can use pretty much any remote repo server/provider. It doesn't have to be Github. (Although the built-in UI is specifically tailored to use Github.)